# Google Direction api

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, google-directions-api

I am implementing google direction api in my android app. It works but it takes time(approx 30sec) to fetch result.How can I reduce this fetching time.
I had enable google direction api on google console but there, I am getting 99% error rate for google direction api.

```
  private DirectionsResult getDirectionsDetails(String origin, String destination, TravelMode mode) {
    mMap.clear();
    DateTime now = new DateTime();
    try {
        return DirectionsApi.newRequest(getGeoContext())
                .mode(mode)
                .origin(origin)
                .destination(destination)
                .departureTime(now)
                .await();
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}

private GeoApiContext getGeoContext() {
    GeoApiContext geoApiContext = new GeoApiContext();
    return geoApiContext
            .setQueryRateLimit(3)
            .setApiKey(getResources().getString(R.string.apikey))
            .setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setReadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setWriteTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

most of your attempts might just timeout, when setting `1s` as all possible timeout values.

... better try to use the `GeoApiContext.Builder()` with it's default settings:

```
private GeoApiContext getGeoApiContext() {
    return new GeoApiContext.Builder()
      .apiKey(getResources().getString(R.string.apikey))
      .build();
}
```